# Predicting orbital trajectory of an object

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, kinematics, orbital-motion, simulations

I'm new here, I'm not a physics student, I'm a programmer and a soon to be computer science student (I come in peace).

I'm developing a space simulation thing and I need your help. I know the velocity vector of a body in a 3d space and the distance between that body and a significantly bigger one. The first body is supposed to orbit the second one. I want to know the equation of the ellipse, the Euler Angle of the ellipse with respect to the reference frame and the argument of peri-apsis of the object.

I thought about just adding a gravitational force to the body, but since it's a simulation, the frame duration being greater than zero causes error accumulation. What I tried to do is to find as many data as possible from the stuff I know, like I found an expression of the semi-major axis and the speed at the apo-apsis using the vis-viva equation, but not much more really.

Comment: *with respect to the reference frame* Which reference frame?

Comment: you may want to read up on the "central force problem" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_central-force_problem) and the "two-body problem" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-body_problem)

Comment: Are you approximating the “significantly bigger” body as being stationary? (If you consider just the Earth-Sun system, the Sun actually moves on a small ellipse.)

Comment: Reading suggestion for programmers : Jean Meeus 'Astronomical algorithms'

Comment: @G.Smith the simulation has an origin and axis directions, that's the reference frame I'm referring to

Comment: @PM2Ring Yes, I know I could use Euler Integration, but I need the orbit to be "on rails" whenever there is no energy change, I don't want the computation to be performance intensive

Comment: @G.Smith also yes, I am approximating the significantly bigger body as being stationary, because it's more of a "planet and spacecraft" situation than a "planet and star" kind of thing

Comment: @planetmaker I will order it as soon as I can :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an algorithm you can implement.

Let the small orbiting body have mass $m$. You know its initial position and velocity vectors, $\mathbf{r}_0$ and $\mathbf{v}_0$, in an arbitrary Cartesian coordinate system.

I’ll assume that you want to treat the “significantly heavier” body with mass $M$ as being stationary and consider it to be the origin of your coordinate system. So in the formulas below I have assumed that $M\gg m$.

From the initial position and velocity you know the (constant) angular momentum,

$$\mathbf{L}=m\mathbf{r}_0\times\mathbf{v}_0\tag1.$$

This vector is perpendicular to the plane of the orbit, so now you know the orbital plane.

From the [*vis-viva* equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbital_mechanics#Velocity)

$$v^2=GM\left(\frac2r-\frac1a\right)\tag2$$

you can use $\mathbf{r}_0$ and $\mathbf{v}_0$ to find the semimajor axis $a$ of the ellipse in this plane.

From the semimajor axis you can find the (constant) energy using

$$E=-\frac{GMm}{2a}\tag3.$$

From the energy and the angular momentum you can find the [orbital eccentricity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbital_eccentricity)

$$e=\sqrt{1+\frac{2EL^2}{G^2M^2m^3}}\tag4.$$

At this point you know the plane of the ellipse, the size of the ellipse, and the eccentricity of the ellipse. The remaining unknown is the orientation of the ellipse in the plane.

To find this, use the orbital equation

$$r=a\frac{1-e^2}{1+e\cos\theta}\tag5$$

where $\theta$ is an angular coordinate around the axis defined by $\mathbf L$, and the expression for the angular momentum in polar coordinates in the orbital plane,

$$L=mr^2\dot\theta\tag6.$$

These equations give the velocity components in terms of the angle around the ellipse as

$$v_r=\dot{r}=\frac{L}{ma}\frac{e\sin\theta}{1-e^2}\tag7$$

and

$$v_\theta=r\dot\theta=\frac{L}{ma}\frac{1+e\cos\theta}{1-e^2}\tag8.$$

You know one velocity, $\mathbf{v}_0$, and can find its $r$ and $\theta$ components. The value of $\theta$ that satisfies both (7) or (8) -- call it $\theta_0$ -- tells you where along the ellipse you’re starting. The major axis of the ellipse is in the direction where $\theta=0$.

ADDENDUM:

Here is a complete numerical example! Use units in which $GM=m=1$, and let the initial position be

$$\mathbf{r}_0=(1,2,3)$$

and the initial velocity be

$$\mathbf{v}_0=\left(\frac12,\frac13,\frac14\right).$$

One finds

$$\mathbf{L}=\left(-\frac12,\frac54,-\frac23\right),$$

$$E=\frac{427-144\sqrt{14}}{2016}\approx -0.0554557,$$

and

$$e=\sqrt{1-\frac{325(144\sqrt{14}-427)}{145152}}\approx 0.86564.$$

The initial radial velocity is

$$v_{r,0}=\mathbf{v}_0\cdot\frac{\mathbf{r}_0}{|\mathbf{r}_0|}=\frac{23}{12\sqrt{14}}\approx 0.512251$$

and the initial velocity along the $\hat\theta$ direction is

$$v_{\theta,0}=\sqrt{\mathbf{v}_0^2-v_{r,0}^2}=\frac{5}{12}\sqrt{\frac{13}{14}}\approx 0.40151.$$

Solving for $\theta_0$, one finds

$$\theta_0=\pi-\tan^{-1}\frac{115\sqrt{13\sqrt{395929+93600\sqrt{14}}}}{184679}\approx 117.277\text{ degrees}.$$

(I used *Mathematica*.)

To represent the orbit, we introduce some useful unit vectors.

A unit vector perpendicular to the orbit is

$$\hat{\mathbf{z}}=\frac{\mathbf{L}}{|\mathbf{L}|}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{13}}\left(-\frac65,3,-\frac85\right)\approx (-0.33282,0.83205,-0.44376).$$

A perpendicular unit vector pointing toward the initial position is

$$\hat{\mathbf{x}}=\frac{\mathbf{r}_0}{|\mathbf{r}_0|}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{14}}(1,2,3)\approx (0.267261,0.534522,0.801784).$$

A third perpendicular unit vector is

$$\hat{\mathbf{y}}=\hat{\mathbf{z}}\times\hat{\mathbf{x}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{182}}\left(\frac{61}{5},2,-\frac{27}{5}\right)\approx (0.904324,0.14825,-0.400275).$$

We rotate around $\hat{\mathbf{z}}$ by $\theta_0$ to make new unit vectors where $\hat{\mathbf{x}}'$ points along the major axis:

$$\hat{\mathbf{x}}'=\hat{\mathbf{x}}\cos{\theta_0}-\hat{\mathbf{y}}\sin{\theta_0}\approx (-0.926249,-0.376731,-0.0116847),$$

$$\hat{\mathbf{y}}'=\hat{\mathbf{x}}\sin{\theta_0}+\hat{\mathbf{y}}\cos{\theta_0}\approx (-0.176901,0.407143,0.896019).$$

The orbit is then

$$\begin{align}
\mathbf{r}&=r(\hat{\mathbf{x}}'\cos\theta+\hat{\mathbf{y}}'\sin\theta)\\
&=a\frac{1-e^2}{1+e\cos\theta}(\hat{\mathbf{x}}'\cos\theta+\hat{\mathbf{y}}'\sin\theta)\\
&=\left(\frac{-2.09049\cos\theta-0.399255\sin\theta}{1+0.86584\cos\theta},\frac{-0.850262\cos\theta+0.9189\sin\theta}{1+0.86584\cos\theta},\frac{-0.0263717\cos\theta+2.02238\sin\theta}{1+0.86584\cos\theta}\right)
\end{align}.$$

I leave it to you to verify, as I did, that this satisfies the initial conditions when $\theta=\theta_0$.

As further sanity checks, one finds that when $\theta=0$ the position is $(-1.1204,-0.455699,-0.0141339)$ and when $\theta=\pi$ it is $(15.5821,6.33768,0.196569)$. The former is periapsis, at a distance of $1.20961$, and the latter is apoapsis, at a distance of $16.8228$. These sum to twice the semimajor axis, $2a\approx 18.0324$, and are individually $a(1-e)$ and $a(1+e)$ with $e\approx 0.86564$.

Note: All of this gets you the correct ellipse in 3D space, parameterized by the angle-around-the-orbit $\theta$. It doesn’t tell you where the object is at a given *time*, which adds more complications because $\theta$ isn’t proportional to $t$. For information about the time-dependence, see the Wikipedia article “[Kepler’s equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler%27s_equation)”.

Comment: A word of caution is to *not assume* that the orbit is ellipsoidal since it can be a parabola or hyperbola depending on the initial (given) distance and speed of the orbiting object. For this reason, while the [p-iteration](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/full/1990CeMDA..48..145G) algorithm is used for interplanetary (ellipsoidal) trajectories, [other methods](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s40295-016-0086-0) are used to determine orbital trajectories. Check out some resources [here](http://hanspeterschaub.info/AVS-Code.html).

Comment: Yes. The orbit is elliptical only if the *vis-viva* equation gives a positive value for $a$.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot for the amazing exhaustive answer! I'll try and implement the algorithm :)

Comment: @kb314 I'll check your resources too, thanks a lot :)

Comment: I realized that you don't really need to solve (7) and (8) for $\theta_0$. You can just get $\cos{\theta_0}$ from (8) and $\sin{\theta_0}$ from (7) and use these trig values to rotate the unit vectors in the orbital plane.